# What are the differences between LDAP and REST interfaces? And which is best?

Tags: web-services, rest, interface, ldap

What are the differences between LDAP and REST interfaces? And which is best?

I have a frontend and a backend(Database). I want to use one of the interfaces between LDAP and REST. So which is best where in terms of availability, scalability, elasticity, performance, data format, flexibility, easiness etc. Or what are the differences between those two interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

LDAP is a standard protocol defined by a series of RFC (check RFC 4510 for the complete reference).
REST is a software architecture style for designing web applications, so it relies on HTTP.
If you do not understand what is LDAP and what are its design principles, use the REST interfaces. It will be easier for you. The other properties won't matter.